# Considering a sum of a monotonically increasing and decreasing sequence.

Tags: analysis, limits

The following is the problem that I am working on.

> Let $\{z_n\} = \{x_n\}+\{y_n\}$ be a sequence where $\{x_n\}$ is monotonically increasing, $\{y_n\}$ monotonically decreasing, and $\{z_n\}$ is bounded.
>
> Is $\{z_n\}$ convergent ? What if $\{x_n\}$ and $\{y_n\}$ are also bounded ?

I can clearly see and prove that in the second case, $\{z_n\}$ must converge to the sum of each of the limits of the sequences (because they exist).

However, this is what I think about the case where only $\{z_n\}$ is bounded.

Intuitively I want to say that it would be nice if $\{z_n\}$ converges but that sounds too good.

So I considered the following case.

If $\{x_n\}$ increases "faster" than $\{y_n\}$ decreasing, $\{z_n\}$ will become a monotonically increasing sequence that is bounded, thus it will converge to the sup of $\{z_n\}$.

If $\{y_n\}$ decreases "faster" then with the similar argument $\{z_n\}$ will converge to the inf.

If their increasing and decreasing rate are equal then it's a constant sequence, so the limit is cogent.

But I am not 100% confident that there doesn't exist a "rate of increase and decrease that lies in between" so that $\{z_n\}$ eventually oscillates or something.

Can someone help me out ?

Comment: It is pretty easy to construct a sequence where $z_i = (-1)^i$, which is bounded but doesn't converge.

Comment: @CalvinLin: From the answers I can see that, thank you. Do you have any more examples so that in the future I can get the idea of what kind of thinking I should be doing ?

Comment: Generally, you should know why a counter-example works, and what 'property' it is exploiting. In this case, we want a bounded sequence that is not convergent, and the typical example is $(-1)^i$ (and equivalently $0,1,0,1,0,1, \ldots$). Then, you can think about how to create such a sequence $z_i$. Of course, it is not guaranteed that this approach always works, so understanding more/various counter-examples will be very helpful.

Comment: You had a good analysis of what happens if $(x_n)$ increases faster than $(y_n)$ decreases, and what happens in the opposite case. All that remained is to realize that, since these are infinite sequences they can switch between the two cases. $(x_n)$ can increase faster than $(y_n)$ decreases for a while, say for $n\leq100$, and then it can be slower for a while, say for $100\leq n\leq200$, and then faster for a while, etc.  That way you can manipulate $(z_n)$ to do just about anything you can imagine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What about something like $ x_n = n + .5 \sin (n) $ and $ y_n = -n + .5 \sin(n) $?

Comment: Wow, this is exactly the reason I was not confident with my argument. Is this a rather common technique ?

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:**  $x_n = \lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor$ and $y_n = - \lfloor \frac{n+1}{2} \rfloor$

Comment: Ohhhhhh, that is clever ! I am not very articulate with the use of floor and roof functions, but this gives me great insight. Thanks !

Comment: @hyg17 Note that you could simply have created the sequences explicitly as $x_n = 0,0,1,1, 2, 2, 3, 3 \ldots $ and $y_n = -0, -1, -1, -2, -2, -3, -3,  \ldots$. It's clear how to continue these sequences, and why it works. The use of floor/ceiling functions merely give a closed form for the sequence, which is not completely necessary.

Comment: Ahh, thanks for loosening up some knots in my head. We are virtually at the same age but our brains are at a different level. lol